# ACE.OLEDB.12 installed but everything has a 0 on sp_msset_oledb_prop

Tags: sql-server-2008

[image]

So I installed ACE.OLEDB.12 to import excel files into sql server. After this, I can acces this procedure to see if everything is ok, but it's not. I have Zeroes on everything. This is a simple question. Should I restart sql server to validade it? I'm asking this because it's a production server and it's really hard to find a free time to restart it. If I'm sure this is going to fix the issue, I can restart it anytime. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to run commands to enable them.

```
   EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO
   EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO
   EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'NestedQueries', 1
GO
   EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'NonTransactedUpdates', 1
GO
   EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'SqlServerLIKE', 1
GO
```

Comment: hey erki thank you for your answer. I can see now that we have those values configures. but still, when I'm trying to import a .xlsx file, sql server says "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine". I installed some patches, restarted the server but I have no idea what to do to imposrt these .xlsx files. I can import .xls at least.